# Displaying 'Add to Cart' on mouse over does not work for similar elementId

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below code for displaying `Add to Cart` `onmouseover`. It works perfectly if there is only 1 item of similar ID, but in certain situation, there can be same `product` displayed multiple time in same page, and there `Add to Cart` button does not show to current object instead it shows to first `element` of that particular `ID`.

```
## Category A ##
<div onmouseover="document.getElementById('addtocart1').style.display='block'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('addtocart1').style.display='hidde'">

<span style="display:none;" id="addtocart1"></span>
          Product A
</div>

## Category B ##
<div onmouseover="document.getElementById('addtocart1').style.display='block'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('addtocart1').style.display='hidde'">

<span style="display:none;" id="addtocart1"></span>
       Product A
</div>
```

How can i set `display:block` to `respective` `object` whenever user takes his/her `mouse`

Thanks

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: First things first you should not have duplicate ID's on a page, an id should be unique

Comment: hmmm... Ok... I will include category wise id too :) Thanks

Comment: display:hidden is not valid CSS. And you also have display:hidde.

Comment: it's either visibility:hidden; or display:none;

Comment: oh! yes.. i fixed that.. that was typo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Your Duplicating the ID's it will Not work . But the bellow code will work. Finlay Why don't You use Jquery It's very easy

onmouseover="this.children[0].style.display='block'" onmouseout="this.children[0].style.display='none'"

Answer (score 1):

As stated in one of the comments on the question, Element IDs **must** be unique. If you want all of the objects to have something in common, try giving them all a class, and then [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) will return an array with all of the elements that have that class. Then loop over that array and do whatever it is you need to do. You'll also want to put all of that in a function that gets called `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`, since you're going to be executing more than one line of code.

Alternatively, if you were to use something like [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), you can use CSS selectors to get the class then, `$('.className').`[`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)`(function)` and `$('.className').`[`mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)`(function)`, will apply that function to all of the elements that have that class.